Sci-fi/fantasy book/series that my sister and I listened to the first audio book of in 2014
I cannot remember a ton of details but my sister and I listened to the first book on audio book around 2014 in the USA in English. The cds and I think by extension the first book cover were blue.
I remember it starts with a normal brother and sister in an apartment and their mother had recently disappeared. They are possibly attacked or chased by some bad people and then rescued by some good people and transported to a magic world with technology that their mother came from and find out she had magical powers. I remember there being some kind of a competition they have to join put on by the king or person in charge and one of the earlier challenges is to get through a an outdoor shrubbery maze. They develop magical powers spell casting I think and train their abilities. The son ends up finding the mother locked in the basement of the castle and he isn’t able to free her but is able to get some advice from her about what to do next. I can’t remember how the book ends if he fight the main bad guy or if the competition ends, I think it continues on to the next book. There may have been some kind of a magical charm or key he was protecting too.
